# .htaccess redirection from urls with no extension to .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have revamped my website from WordPress to PHP. Now every url with no extension are showing a 404 error page. I have checked with many redirect codes but all are not working. Please suggest a solution for this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please provide your current `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]    This I checked but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```